# Compile python scripts with C++ project

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a C++ project that invokes the same function in each python script. But each script does very different things that need access to the C++ project's internal classes.

So I need a python wrapper so I pass a C++ object to the python script and I need a way to run the python script's function from the C++ project too.

From what I understand with Cython and Shed Skin they are utilities to make C++ classes into a python class but not necessarily share run time objects back and forth between the languages.

What can I do?

Comment: This is a very broad question, however you could look at Boost for Python.

Comment: Let's say I have a program written in C++ that connects to a database. I want this program to execute 5 python scripts. Those python scripts should call functions from the program to access specific run-time data and return some values back to the program.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you Maverick for your question.
Cython is not a way of using C++ classes into python.Cython is simply python with c data types.Means that you can use c data types in your python program which in turn turns your python code to execute faster.Also you can build extensions in python using cython.
Now comming to the problem in the question,you can use boost library for your task.In boost you just need to write a wrapper to use your c++ object in python or vice versa.You just need to compile it to a shared library which can be done by tools like jam,cython etc.I am not going into details of how you are going to do it as you can find many tutorials for the same.

Comment: This isn't true. [Cython __is__ a way of using C++ classes in Python](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).